# Can I freeze an entire web part?

Tags: web-part, custom, move

If I have an excel web part and I would like to freeze the whole web part so that when I scroll down the list, the excel web part is still valuable, is this possible?

I have used the freeze column header (sticky header) for just that, column headers, however I would like a similar fix for an entire web part.

SharePoint 2013. IE10, no SharePoint Designer. I have to be able to be able to insert script or use a .js reference in a CEWP.

Comment: Hello I am able to use the information above to freeze the web part. However it just displays over the other web part pages when I scroll. See the image below. Is there a way to fix this?
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP7LC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP7LC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CSS positioning property `position: fixed` on the web part to keep it static on the page. You'll need to grab the ID of the web part using your browser's developer tools and then set the CSS property either directly in the CEWP or through a script.

Here's an example using CSS on a specific web part with the ID of `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2` :

```
<style>

    #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 {
        position: fixed;
    }

</style>
```

Here's an example using jQuery on the same web part:

```
<script src="/location-of-your-jquery-file/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2").css("position", "fixed");

    });

 </script>
```